# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm trying to collapse and expand a UITableView section with the help of deleteRowsAtIndexPaths. Nothing seems to happen though and I can't figure out why.

```
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=1; i<numberOfRowsInSection; i++){
        NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
        [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
    }

    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [_tableView endUpdates];
```

I've read through a lot of related questions, but nothing I do seem to help.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Seems like _tableview is null. I'm guessing that's the main reason nothing is happening. Just don't understand that, since tableview is an outlet and it's already filled with rows and sections.

How can a tableview that's filled with rows and sections be null?

Comment: Seems odd. Are you sure `_tableView` isn't `nil`?

Comment: It is. How in the world can it be null if it has a lot of content (sections and rows) and is hooked up with an IBOutlet?

Comment: Well, how in the world would I know that when the only place `_tableView` is used in your code are the three last lines in the code you shared???

Comment: My guess is that there is some basic mistake - e.g. `_tableView` is `nil` or `numberOfRowsInSection` is zero. Debugging should find the mistake really fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deleteRowAtIndexPath:withAnimation:` just tells your table how it should display the table. You need to remove this row from your actual data at the same time. Aka `tableView:NumberOfRowsInSection:` need to return the correct number of lines.

Comment: If he doesn't remove the row and he calls `deleteRow...`, he gets a table state exception.

Comment: @nsgulliver thanks for the suggestion. You're right that I'm not moving the data from my tableview data. Do I really need to do that? All I really have to do is "hide" the rows, not delete them. I think the main error is the one I've updated my question with though!

Answer (score 0):

you might be reloading the table view with original data after calling `deleteRowsAt...` make sure to change update your tableView data source in order to cope with the deleted changes  i.e change the number of rows per section in the method `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Think the real problem is the one I've written in the question above though. Btw... do I really need to remove the rows from the tableview data as well? I just want to hide the rows, not delete them!

Comment: no you don't have to remove them unless you are reloading the table view with the same data source